# What does “let alone brain anybody with” mean?

Tags: meaning

Yet another a part of *Circular Staircase*, by Mary Rinehart:

> "Not out in the hall!" she gasped; "Oh, Miss Rachel, not out in the
>   hall!" trying to hold me back.  But I am a large woman and Liddy is
>   small.  We got to the door, somehow, and Liddy held a brass andiron,
>   which it was all she could do to lift, **let alone brain anybody with.**  I
>   listened, and, hearing nothing, opened the door a little and peered
>   into the hall.

Are any words omitted in the sentence that includes *let alone brain anybody with*?  Something looks missing from this sentence.

Comment: The answer to the question you’ve asked is no — or in full: “No, no words have been left out.”  We cannot answer your real question, however, because you have not told us what it is yet. Why would you think words went missing here? What bit isn’t connecting up the way you are thinking it should?

Comment: @tchrist - If the idiom 'to brain [somebody]' is unfamiliar to the questioner (who is therefore unable to make grammatical sense of it), one possible inference on the questioner's part is that something necessary for proper comprehension could have been omitted from the sentence; but what likely starting point would the questioner have to hypothesize what that missing something was? If you had instead asked them "Did you actually look up the word *brain* to check all the ways in which it can be used?", then I would have agreed with you.

Comment: It _is_ rather involved and sounds clumsy to my ears. Here are progressively more complicated relatives: Liddy held a brass andiron. It was all she could do to lift it, let alone brandish it. // Liddy held a brass andiron. It was all she could do to lift it, let alone use it as a weapon. // Liddy held a brass andiron. It was all she could do to lift it, let alone hit anybody on the head with it.

Comment: The question is clear, and the answer correct. I cannot fathom why this was put on hold; there are clearly several members if the community who understand it. Perhaps the vocal VTC minority should consider the possibility they are missing something.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod If that’s what the OP meant, she should’ve said so—but she didn’t. ***Plus it’s GR if so!*** We don’t know what she doesn’t get: syntax, definitions, punctuation, connotation, &c. **She needs to edit this post** to say exactly what she’s talking about **and to show her previous research** so we can see where her confusion lies. She’s been a member here for a year now: she should know all this, and how to format things, too. [Her question history](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/58207/user58207?tab=questions&sort=newest) shows a consistent pattern here, one which needs work.

Comment: I would be the first to admit that I suffer from a deficit in the creativity department, but I cannot for the life of me think of another way to interpret this question outside of what its title says: What does "let alone brain anybody with" mean. I would accept GR for a closure reason.

Comment: The question I had about that passage was "what the heck is an andiron?". Wikipedia to the rescue `An andiron (older form anderne; med. Lat. andena, anderia) is a horizontal iron bar upon which logs are laid for burning in an open fireplace.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To "brain" someone is to hit them on the head, usually with some sort of heavy object.  The implication of the quote is that Liddy would not have been able to use the andiron as a weapon.

Comment: I think she just can’t figure out the parse: hence the missing-word question. This won’t format prettily in a comment, but I don’t think she realizes that her sentence actually parses out to something like this: (S (NP (NNP Liddy)) (VP (VBD held) (NP (NP (DT a) (NN brass) (NN
andiron)) (, ,) (SBAR (WHNP (WDT which)) (S (NP (PRP it)) (VP (VBD
was) (NP (NP (DT all)) (SBAR (S (NP (PRP she)) (VP (MD could) (VP
(VB do) (S (VP (VP (TO to) (VP (VB lift)) (, ,) (CC let alone) (VP
(VB brain) (NP (NN anybody)) (ADVP with)))))))))))))))) (. .)).

Comment: I don’t see this as answering her question, because I can’t tell what her question is. Maybe you’ve guessed it, but maybe you haven’t.  I’m withholding judgement until she tells us her real question.

Comment: If the Op's question, "What does 'let alone brain anybody with' mean?", seems quite clear to me and @Hot Licks gives the correct answer. It seems that a colloquialism, conversation between people so familiar with each other's speech that they are able to converse in a form of oral shorthand without loss of meaning, prevented the OP from arriving at the sentence's import. Omitting words is the hallmark of colloquial speech and the OP noticed that.

Comment: The question is quite clear (stated in the heading, with context added in the body), and this post answers it. IMO too many questions get closed as "Unclear ...".

Comment: @tchrist I don't understand your comment. What notation are you using?

Comment: @EllieKesselman - I think it's LISP.

Comment: The notation is that produced, in this case, by the Stanford Parser, a rather standard tool using in NLP. It shows how things fit together, although without newlines and indentation for proper formatting and understanding, it requires experience to read.

Comment: @tchrist It looks so funny, all glommed together in a comment!  Oooh, you could have used the forbidden `code mark-up`! It would have been justifiable in this case!